# how to uncheck the other section radio buttons while selecting another section of radio button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

i am new to react please help me in clarifying this question.
i would like to uncheck the radio of section while selecting another section. i am using material ui radioGroup. please use the link to code sandbox for the code changes. https://codesandbox.io/s/5sdne?file=/demo.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import RadioGroup, { useRadioGroup } from '@mui/material/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Radio from '@mui/material/Radio';

const StyledFormControlLabel = styled((props) => <FormControlLabel {...props} />)(
  ({ theme, checked }) => ({
    '.MuiFormControlLabel-label': checked && {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  }),
);

function MyFormControlLabel(props) {
  const radioGroup = useRadioGroup();

  let checked = false;

  if (radioGroup) {
    checked = radioGroup.value === props.value;
  }

  return <StyledFormControlLabel checked={checked} {...props} />;
}

MyFormControlLabel.propTypes = {
  /**
   * The value of the component.
   */
  value: PropTypes.any,
};

export default function UseRadioGroup() {
  return (
    <>
    <p>group A</p>
    <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue="first">
      <MyFormControlLabel value="first" label="First" control={<Radio />} />
      <MyFormControlLabel value="second" label="Second" control={<Radio />} />
    </RadioGroup>
    <p>group B </p>
    <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue="first">
      <MyFormControlLabel value="three" label="three" control={<Radio />} />
      <MyFormControlLabel value="four" label="four" control={<Radio />} />
    </RadioGroup>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: I  see only one radio group (RadioGroup) in your code sandbox. Do you want to have two radio groups and then when clicking on the radio of group A to clear all radios in group B?

Comment: yes, i want to two radio groups and to clear radio in grop B, when clicking on radio on group A

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling your `checkboxes` with a third-party library it's very hard, but don't worry, with some changes, you can achieve your goal.

First:

> React will re-rerender the components or elements with their `key` changes.

So, we can implement a procedure that does some changes in `key` property of the `RadioGroup` component, but as you set the `defaultValue` it needs some trick to work properly and deselect other checkboxes on other groups

```
export default function UseRadioGroup() {
  const [defaultValueA, setDefaultValueA] = React.useState('first');
  const [defaultValueB, setDefaultValueB] = React.useState('three');

  const [keGroupA, setKeyGroupA] = React.useState("a");
  const [keyGroupB, setKeyGroupB] = React.useState("b");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    switch(value){
      case "first":
      case "second":
        setKeyGroupB(prevState => prevState + "a");
        setDefaultValueB(undefined)
        break;
      case "three":
      case "four":
        setKeyGroupA(prevState => prevState + "b");
        setDefaultValueA(undefined)
        break;
      default:
       return
    }
  }


  return (
    <>
      <p>group A</p>
      <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue={defaultValueA} key={keyGroupA} onChange={handleChange}>
        <MyFormControlLabel value="first" label="First" control={<Radio />}/>
        <MyFormControlLabel value="second" label="Second" control={<Radio />} />
      </RadioGroup>
      <p>group B </p>
      <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue={defaultValueB} key={keyGroupB} onChange={handleChange}>
        <MyFormControlLabel value="three" label="three" control={<Radio />} />
        <MyFormControlLabel value="four" label="four" control={<Radio />} />
      </RadioGroup>
    </>
  );
}
```

##### Explanation:

with changes on your checkboxes, the `onChange` method will invoke, so the `handleChange` function determines the other checkboxes with `value` of the selected checkbox.

If you select a checkbox from group A, so the value should be `first` or `two`, so all the other checkboxes ("tree" and "four" in this example) should be unchecked, we make it by changing the `key` on group B with `setKeyGroupB` method.

Also, we need to clear the default on group B. why?

After a change on `key`, group B will re-render so it gets its default value (here is `three`). to avoid this behavior, another state variable has been defined and gets changes in the switch/case block.

**Note:** It's not the best way to do such things, but as a standard solution in these scenarios, you can use it nicely.

Comment: thank you for the solution and clear explanation